# Ruby: No parameter passed in controller function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to pass parameters to the controller function `view` but no parameter passed in. Please help me figure out the problem. How can I pass the parameter?
PostsController:

```
  def view
    if params[:id].nil?
      print("null")
    end
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

show.html.erb(where I can the function `view`):

```
  <% if current_user.username == @user.username %>
    <td> Yourself </td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= link_to @post.author, posts_view_path(@post)%></td>
  <% end %>
```

The problem is that if I change the line `posts_view_path(@post)` to `edit_post_path(@post)`, the parameter is passed successfully.
There is my `edit` function:

```
def edit
  if params[:id].nil?
    print("null")
  end
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thus, I wonder if I define the function in the wrong way? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is in how your posts_view_path is defined in your routes.rb, so if you could include that?  It should be something like `resources :posts do; member do; get :view; end;end` and the expected name for the path is "view_post_path(@post)"

Comment: So TL;DR... please include the relevant part of your `routes.rb` in your question, please.

Comment: If you want to declare a route that displays the posts belonging to an author you would create a nested route as per my answer. While @SteveTurczyn's ducktape solution might "fix" the problem its still a really bad solution to a problem thats covered by the Rails conventions.

Answer (score 0):

your routes declaration is not correct. Please try with this.

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :posts do
  get :view, on: :member
end
```

Comment: I make @SteveTurczyn comment as an answer. Please accept it. Maybe it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way to create a page that shows the posts belonging to a single author would be to declare [a nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :authors do
  resources :posts, only: :index, module: :authors 
end
```

This creates the route `GET /authors/1/posts` which RESTfully describes the relationship between the two resources. You can see just by looking at the url that it represents posts belonging to author 1 - compare this to `posts/view?id=1` which is non-RESTful. And note here that we are passing the id of the author - not a post.

```
# app/controllers/authors/posts_controller.rb
module Authors
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_author
    
    # GET /authors/1/posts
    def index
      @posts = @author.posts
    end

    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Setting up a separate controller for the nested representation is really optional - while you could have shorehorned this into your PostsController having a separate controller rhymes well with the single responsibility principle.

To link to a nested resource you can use the named helper:

```
link_to @post.author, author_posts_path(@post.author)
```

Or the polymorphic routing helpers:

```
link_to @post.author, [@post.author, :posts]
```

Comment: I'm going to ignore the big elephant in the room which is that you're storing the name of the author instead of an id and setting up an association and also making some assumptions here about the models so that I can explain the actual concepts instead of getting bogged down in code salvaging.  This code is not indended as a straight copy paste solution and requires some research and thinking.